# knockout click event only triggers on initialization

Tags: html, events, knockout.js

I want a clickable div that toggles the visibility of my underlying details view.

```
<div class="header" data-bind="click: Details(!Details())">
...
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: Details()"></div>
```

Details is stored in my knockout model and it's default value is false. When I add this section the function gets called and the details become visible. And after that the div is clickable (different mouse pointer when hovering) but the value in the knockout model no longer gets changed.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click binding takes a function reference so you need to wrap your handler into an anonymous function:

```
<div class="header" data-bind="click: function() { Details(!Details()) }">
```

In your current code the `Details(!Details())` gets executed when the biding is initialized and the return value of the `Details(...)` which is undefined get assigned as the handler so that is why it not worked after that.

See also the [click binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html): Accessing the event object, or passing more parameters section.

Comment: Thanks, only these elements are added multiple times and currently clicking one toggles all of them. Any idea's on how to make them individual? Anyway your answer is great, I had to wait before accepting so I'm running into the next problem :P

Comment: How do you add them multiple times, whit a `foreach`? Without seeing your complete model and how your UI built up it is hard to tell what is not wired correctly, if you still have this problem you should ask it in a different question with providing the above mentioned details.